# Pandas query or eval when there is `.` in the column name

Tags: python, pandas

How can I use column names in pandas `query` or `eval` method when the column name has `.` in it. For example, the dataframe has `.` in its column name `first.last`

`df = pd.DataFrame({'first.last':[10, 20, 30, 40]})`

As a result I can't run the following expression 
`df.query('first.last < 30')`

Are there any ways to mitigate this or work around this ? Thanks

Comment: Common issue for query https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6508

Comment: Thanks. Looks like there is a PR ready to merge `https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/28215` to take care of this issue.

Comment: I used `_clean_special_characters_column_name` method available in the PR for the time being to map old column names to new column names and used the new column names in the query expression

Answer (score 2):

You could rename the columns. Please try:

```py
cols = df.columns
cols = cols.map(lambda x: x.replace('.', '_') if isinstance(x, (str, unicode)) else x)
df.columns = cols
```

Comment: Thanks @hrmnjt. But the above approach will cause collisions if there is an additional column name `first_last`.

Comment: You could choose to replace the column name with special format like `___` to avoid collision. Just trying to help here with money tricks as this is a known issue that is pending to be implemented into pandas core code.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the dataframe like this:

```
df[df['first.last'] < 30]
```

Comment: That's true. I am trying to use `query` or `eval` method for the step.

Comment: According to the documentation (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.eval.html#pandas.eval), the string needs to be a valid python expression, which 'first.last < 30' is not, because '.' has a special meaning. You can check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40045545/pandas-query-string-where-column-name-contains-special-characters The second answer offers a nice hack.